# When calling GetComputerNameA, the program crash without errors

Tags: winapi, autoit, computer-name

I am trying to call `GetComputerNameA` from AutoIt, this is my code:

```
Local $mystruct = DllStructCreate(toStr("struct;dword;char[1024];endstruct"))
DllStructSetData($mystruct, 1, 1024)
Local $result = DllCall("kernel32.dll", "int", "GetComputerNameA", "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($mystruct, 2), "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($mystruct, 1))
MsgBox(0, "AutoIt", "Success")
```

But after I run it, it doesn't print anything, like the script crashed without errors.
Any idea why it failed to call it?

Comment: GetComputerNameA doesn't take a structure as a parameter. Read the documentation at Microsoft for the function parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has two parameters, [specifically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcomputernamea):

```
BOOL GetComputerNameA(
  LPSTR   lpBuffer,
  LPDWORD nSize
);
```

The first is a `LPSTR` (pointer to a `char` array), the second is a `LPDWORD` (pointer to an `unsigned int`).

Here is how you'd call that:

```
Func _get_computer_name()
    Local $dll_struct = DllStructCreate("char[17]")
    
    $sz = DllStructCreate('int')
    Local $x = DllCall("kernel32.dll","int","GetComputerNameA","ptr",DllStructGetPtr($dll_struct),"int_ptr",DllStructGetPtr($sz))

    Return DllStructGetData($dll_Struct,1)
EndFunc
```